# R Problems with glm-model due to missing values

Tags: r, regression, missing-data, glm, poisson

I have problems with putting my data into a glm model. I think the problem is because I have many missing values in my data (below). I tried this so far:

```
baseformula = as.formula(df)
glm(baseformula, data = df, family = poisson(link = "log"), na.action = na.exclude)
```

I am getting an Error:

> Error in glm.fit(x = numeric(0), y = integer(0), weights = NULL, start
>   = NULL,  :    object 'fit' not found

Can somebody help me with this? When a variable is NA in my formula, I just want the glm to ignore the NAs and use these variables the same as variables without NA.

```
structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), V48 = c(97.33, 96.88, 85.33, 83.75, 75.58, 86.13, 83, 95.75, 
88.46, 80.25, 75, 67.17, 69.33, 64.08, 70.75, 78.46, 85.58, 83.42, 
96.17, 76.5, 76.42, 65.38, 69.79, 68.38, 84.67, 89.67, 91.29, 
80.54, 64.63, 72.29, 76.54, 65.33, 96.92, 91.38, 88.92, 80.63, 
85.5, 76.38, 76.21, 78.29, 89.29, 87.04, 78.67), V49 = c(-0.9, 
-0.1, 0, 0.9, -0.2, -6.3, -4.9, -1.2, -0.3, -1.4, 7.3, 10.5, 
10.8, 17.5, 10.8, 9.2, 7.3, 8.2, 10.2, 8.5, 10.4, 25.6, 26.7, 
28, 20.1, 20.2, 15.7, 15.3, 21.6, 24.8, 22.4, 27.1, 14.3, 13.8, 
17.1, 19.5, 22.9, 21.9, 17.2, 18.9, 16.3, 14.2, 18.5), V58 = c(0.16208333, 
-0.02576069, -0.24859501, -0.39733779, -0.35568168, -0.13908246, 
-0.11529523, -0.07094469, 0.07592036, 0.13803538, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V59 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.40727943, 0.44007391, 0.50582446, 0.59001139, 
0.55057958, 0.53888617, 0.55019019, 0.42592698, 0.347516, 0.52019593, 
0.69611622, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V61 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.04555282, 0.16109391, 0.13651381, -0.02339007, 
-0.24799358, -0.14477839, -0.0845835, -0.13505766, -0.06910931, 
0.05876354, 0.11372484, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), V68 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.01575957, 
-0.19924471, -0.39083879, -0.26620543, -0.10669409, -0.05650572, 
0.06644096, 0.24769837, -0.11404654, -0.49358358, -0.27725445, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V71 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.1563703, -0.23797044, -0.37304736, -0.27425744, 
-0.02347071, 0.36391633, 0.44316418, 0.21940339, 0.02321926, 
-0.01531807, -0.05197635, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V73 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.46298985, 
-0.7644245, -0.82771396, -0.81243484, -0.75591058, -0.55440085, 
-0.35516327, -0.05602486, -0.12290976, -0.14458255, -0.17033091
), V77 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.04571093, 0.25592819, 0.35649173, 0.3507695, 0.30446594, 
0.36505183, 0.54215354, 0.47808018, 0.40325075, 0.32091592, 0.09212919
)), .Names = c("V1", "V48", "V49", "V58", "V59", "V61", "V68", 
"V71", "V73", "V77"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
70L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 
162L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 
254L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you remove all the NA rows from all of the variables (V58 through V77 in particular) you remove all of the data.  Take a look at `na.omit(df)`; you get a 0 row dataset..

Comment: Yes I know, but thats not what I want. I want the glm to ignore the NA und use the rows that contain a value. All of the columns of 59 are not complete empty.

Comment: Not sure what "use these variables the same as variables without NA" means. This is not possible as variables with information cannot be used in the same way as variables without information (for each particular case / row).

Comment: Ok, but I want to run the model with the NAs, I dont want to exclude those, because, as you said, i would have an empty dataframe.

Comment: One option would be to write out the formula manually, since then you can put only the variables you are interested in the model.  Other than that, I think your main option is to select the columns you want in the formula and then use that data.frame.  Like `library(dplyr); select_if(df, ~!any(is.na(.)) )` (but assigning the new data.frame without the columns that have NA to a new name).

Comment: Ok, well I think thats also not the solution that I want. The problem is that I have 6000 dataframes and I have to automatize everything completely.